# Node.js reusing function

Tags: node.js

i have written a function  in file hello.js

---

```
dep1=require('dependency');
function hello(Args, callback){
    modifiedData= dep1.someFunction(Args);
    console.log(modifiedData);
    callback(modifiedData);
}
module.exports=hello;
```

---

how would i re-use this function in other file?

```
h=require("./hello");
h.hello("Howdy!", function(err,args){
    do something;
}
```

Any pointers?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That looks acceptable, although it is a bit hard to read. But when your callback has `err` as the first argument, make sure you send a `null` object as the first parameter:

```
callback(null, modifiedData);
```

When you are using `module.exports`, then the module itself can be called as that function. So you will reuse that function like this:

```
h = require("./hello");
h("Howdy!", function(err, args) {
    //do smth
});
```

Otherwise, in order for your example to work, just delete `module.` and add the name (can be a different one):

```
exports.hello = hello;
```

Comment: Thanks Randunel, i was calling hello.hello so it was throwing error.

Comment: how to import all functions of that file? for each function i need to write  exports.fun1=fun1,exports.fun2=fun2...n time?